# How to create dynamic select field with values from a view?

Tags: views, 7, webforms, entities

I need a dynamic select field to display a drop down box with results from a view. I'm using entityform to design the webform. Does anyone knows how to create such as a field?

The view is populated from a xml feed with data from an external database. View results will be an unformatted list, which is what I need to display in the drop down box within the form for users to select one.

Please help! I'm trying to avoid querying the external database to get the results. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried https://www.drupal.org/project/ddf ?

Comment: I used entityreference_dynamicselect_widget module to generate an array with the view results I wanted to display within the drop down field. A custom module allowed me to dynamically set the options for the drop down using form_alter.